# Large range input single level shifter

Tags: digital-logic, serial, communication, level-shifting, logic-level

I have an application where I will be taking serial signals will need to level shift the signal to 3.3V. The input signal will be from 15 to 5V for a high input and I need them all shifted down to 3.3V.

I understand how to do this when there is one constant input voltage but in this situation, depending on what is connected to my RS232 connector I could have..

-10 to 10V

0 to 5V

0 to 15V

on the input side. Does anyone know a good option to make sure that all of these 3 different signals can be shifted down to 0-3.3V?

I'm struggling to find a solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: is it just input or do you need it to transmit aswell?

Comment: Its single directional -- meaning that its always a higher voltage to 3.3V

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple clamping circuit would do the trick. The diodes will make sure the voltage seen by the buffer is never more than 3.3+Vd and never less than 0-Vd (where Vd is the diode forward voltage). Additionally, the 1K resistor provided current limiting.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdjQ6O.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Would something like http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lv1t34.pdf be a good option for the buffer?

Comment: If you are going to use this circuit you should increase the value of R1 to be as high as possible. 10k would be a minimum value, 47k would be better. Having R1 as 1k means that you are dumping up to 11mA of current onto your 3.3V rail where it will appear as noise in phase with the signal. Whether you can get away with this will depend on the load on the 3.3V rail from the rest of your circuit, but as a general rule you should aim to keep your main 3.3V rail as clean as possible. Increasing the value of R1 reduces the current dumped onto the 3.3V rail and reduces the noise.

Comment: @SteveG is correct, I meant to make the value of R1 larger.

Comment: I can do 47K no problem. Thanks for the clarification. Can someone explain why I would want to use a standard diode vs a zener?

Comment: Zeners are slower than conventional and schottky diodes

Comment: okay sounds good. So im pretty much looking for a conventional or schottky diode with a very low forward voltage and a reverse voltage of greater than 15 V? Thanks for all of the help

Comment: @mitch33 Yup, that's the general idea. That buffer you selected has no limits on input voltage being above supply voltage, so you can power it at 3.3V and apply 4V  (as with a conventional 0.7V diode drop) to the input no problem.